# Confirmation dialog on an ActionLink using ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone know how to add a confirmation dialog with an "actionlinkwithimage"?

Answer (score 5):

You can just add a javascript `confirm` to your `ActionLink` like:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(a => a.ID, "Go", new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" })%
```

**EDIT:** Not sure if you need to know how to implement an `ActionLink` with an image but here is a helper function that can add an image to an `ActionLink`:

```
public static string ActionLinkImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string imagePath, string altText, string actionName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    string replaceText = "ActionLinkImageReplaceMe";
    string linkHtml = System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(htmlHelper, 
        replaceText, actionName, routeValues,htmlAttributes);
    return linkHtml.Replace(replaceText,
        String.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}'/>", imagePath, altText));
}
```

Comment: @ Kelsey -- how would I trigger a confirmation from server side? My "html.ActionLinkWithImage" calls an action from the controller, which I would like to have a confirmation before executing the code within the action. How would I go about this?

Comment: @hersh do you need to check something server side to do the confirmation?  You could do an ajax post call to a confirmation action in your script and then prompt the `confirm` if necessary.  If you want to stick to all server side call then you are going to need an intermediate step to do the server side confirm and display a view etc... then that page would post the completion.  This is a bit more complicated because you need to store the posted data over this confirm page.